# Making a dictionary from many lists with same type of values without using special packages

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, group-by

I have a csv file that I read with Python csv package (not allowed to use pandas, dataFrame etc). I've transformed each row of the csv file to a list of date, id and a score between 0 to 1, so now I have list with many lists:
[['01/03/2019', '1020', '0.770219907'], ['01/03/2019', '1024', '1'], ['01/03/2019', '1031', '1']]

I want to create a dictionary that will take all the dates and count to each date the number of IDs with a score of more than 0.75.

The output should look like this:
{('01/03/2019': 10), '01/04/2019': 45)...}
Which means the for 01/03/2019 I have 10 IDs with a score of more than 0.75

Comment: Can you share what's the expected outputs?

Comment: @DanielHao I added in the question

Comment: OK. Could you try to update my posed code first? And I can help you later if any other questions.

Comment: It works. Thanks! :) BTW, I to make the code to skip the first row of the titles, So I had to add '[1:]' at 'for record in lists:'

Comment: That's great. Congrats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what's the output format you want, but this code should give you some idea on how to proceed:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> scores = defaultdict(list)
>>> for record in lists:
    date, idd, score = record
    if float(score) > 0.75:
        scores[date].append(idd)

        
>>> scores
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'01/03/2019': ['1020', '1024', '1031']})
```